# MVC Checkbox select one item from list and disable the other based on this selection

Tags: jquery

```
Group 1         Group 2         Group 3
Subject 1           Subject 4           Subject 7
Subject 2           Subject 5           Subject 8
Subject 3           Subject 6           Subject 9
```

i have this view all as a checkbox i would like check group 1 if this have a special status disabled the other group and related subjects 
or if have links to other group enable only the linked group and disabled the other in MVC

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $('#Group1').prop('checked')==true) {

  $("#Group2 #Group3").attr("disabled", true);
  $(".sub2 .sub3").attr("disabled", true);
}
else {
 $("#Group2 #Group3").attr("disabled", false);
 $(".sub2 .sub3").attr("disabled", false);
   }
```

assume .sub2 And .sub3 are the class name for all sub checkboxes in group 2 and group 3 respectively.

Comment: but group 1 and group 2 and group 3 not static data  its dynamic data

Comment: please share what you have done. it will help us to understand.